# livecode retrieve record from sqlite

Tags: database, sqlite, livecode

i have a table in sqlite with table name birthday,and rows >id,name,day,month.
i get from my array the system date and convert it to this (day/month).
im using the dblib from andre to retrieve it like the code bellow

```
 on mouseUp
  put the system date into tdate
   convert tDate to short system date
convert tDate to dateitems 
  --put (the item 3 of tDate) & "/" & (the item 2 of tDate) into field "birthday"
  put (the item 3 of tDate) & "/" & (the item 2 of tDate) into today

  dbcolumns "day,month"
  put dbGet("giortes") into myRecords
  repeat for each key tKey in myRecords
    put myRecords[tKey]["day"] &"/"& myRecords[tKey]["month"] & cr after myGiortes[1]
  end repeat
put 0 into check
put false into verify
repeat for each line tempItem in myGiortes[1]
   add 1 to t
   if tempItem = today then
      put true into check
      exit repeat
   end if
end repeat
if check then
  --!! test
  put today into fld tfld

end if

end mouseUp
```

so i get the result in the array like this **12/08**.
is possible to match the result with a row in the sqlite?
I have reproduce the code above.
i get the results from the array and match it with system date converted.
now i want to get all the Row from the database ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snipper it very brief. It might help if you posted the dbGet function, for example. Are you sure that myRecords is an array? You can check this with

```
if myRecords is an array then
```

It isn't clear which row and column delimiters you use, but I assume they are linefeed and tab. You might do the following:

```
dbcolumns "day,month"
put dbGet("giortes") into myRecords
if myRecords is not an array then split myRecords by return and tab
repeat for each key tKey in myRecords
  put myRecords[tKey]["day"] &"/"& myRecords[tKey]["month"] & cr after myGiortes[1]
end repeat
```

Obviously, this only works if myRecords not being an array is the culprit. If there is a problem with your SQL syntax, myRecords could be empty or contain different keys.

If myRecords actually is an error and you just want to find the tkey's for which day=12 and month=8, you can adjust your repeat loop:

```
repeat for each key tKey in myRecords
  if myRecords[tKey]["day"] is 12 and myRecords[tKey]["month"] is 8 then
    put myRecords[tKey]["day"] &"/"& myRecords[tKey]["month"] & cr after myGiortes[1]
  end if
end repeat
```

You might also do this directly using the correct SQL syntax on the database:

```
put "SELECT * FROM giortes WHERE day='12' AND month='8'" into mySQL
// I start variables with "my", it isn't a reference to MySQL
put revDataFromQuery(cr,tab,gDatabaseID,mySQL) into myGiortes
if myGiortes begins with "revdberr" then
  beep
  answer error myGiortes
else
  split myData by cr and tab
end if
```

You also need to make a connection with revOpenDatabase. For this, you need to know the path to the SQLite file.

```
put revOpenDatabase("sqlite",mySQliteFilePath,,,) into gDatabaseID
```

After this line, you can run the previous code snipper. Declare gDatabaseID as a global variable at the top of the script.

**Update 1**

If you prefer to use Andre's database, you can use the dbWhere command:

```
set the itemDel to slash
put item 1 of the date into myMonth
put item 2 of the date into myDay
dbColumns "day,month,id" // I have added id
dbWhere "month",myMonth
dbWhere "day",myDay
put dbGet("giortes") into myGiortes
dbResetQuery
```

This should be sufficient to answer your question. You need no repeat loop any more. I just wonder why you would want this, because now you only get a list like:

```
1  12,8
2  12,8
3  12,8
etc
```

If you want to know the number of records, you might want to use SQLite's COUNT function instead.

**Update 2**

I have changed the code under "Update 1". If you are indeed just looking or the ID of a person who has his birthday today, then you can use `dbColumns "id"` instead of `dbColumnds "day,month,id"`. This would make much more sense, because the sample data in my previous example are useless. If you run the modified code, you should get data similar to

```
1  12,8,1
2  12,8,11
3  12,8,23
etc
```

i.e. the last column contains the ID numbers. You could also just retrieve the ID numbers. if you do that, you get

```
1  1
2  11
3  23
etc
```

Comment: i have reproduce the code above and here is the link for the funcions. [link]http://www.andregarzia.com/aux/dblibguide/[/link]

Comment: I'll have a look at the link, but on Stackoverflow it is considered a good habit to not link to code but to include it all in the question.

Comment: the link is the funcions that i use in my code.THE code of andre is is librarys so i can do it because is locked.just look in the code i have edit in my original post,if that help..

Comment: i have see the update on your post,and is the default answer for a staic search in database...like i say the dates is System days so is [b]random[/b]will be (12/08,12/09 or 02/02) that is my problem..to retrieve spesific record with dbwhere or with sql is ok,but how we do with random?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "random" here. Do you want to find today's date in the database or do you really want a random date?

Comment: maybe i put the question wrong in last comment..
the date we get in the field or the array is for every day.SO every day the code above is looking if the date on array or the field exist in the database,IF exist we need to get all the row (id,name,day,month,etc)

Comment: Please explain "every day"? Do you mean that the script should run every day, searching the database for the current date? Or do you want to find all dates in the database? If you want to find all dates in the database, then your original script was correct.

Comment: **that** >the script should run every day, searching the database for the current date!!

Comment: See Update 2 for my answer to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to find the birthday of the current user then put that id of the current user into the 'myUserId' variable and use the following dbWhere clause from Andre's framework

```
dbWhere "id",myUserId
```

Of course you may be trying to accomplish something different?